# Can I schedule prints to start at a specified time?

Tags: octoprint

I want to know if it is possible to schedule a 3D Print to start at a specified time so that I don't have to press start. 

My 3D Printer has an Arduino mega based RAMPS 1.4 control board & is connected to a Raspberry Pi 3B running OctoPi 0.15.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few options to delay starting using either the OctoPrint environment or directly use G-code for this.

The use of G-code is probably the most simple for you to implement. The [`G4`](https://reprap.org/wiki/G-code#G4:_Dwell) command defines a "dwell" or pausing period for the next command to start:

[image: G4 Dwell G-code]

Depending on the firmware you use, you can use the `P` or `S` parameter to specify the pausing period.

To pause the print job (for 1 hour) you need to insert the following line as the first line of your G-code print file:

```
G4 P3600000 // One hour pausing; defined in milliseconds
```

or (if your firmware supports)

```
G4 S3600 // One hour pausing; defined in seconds
```

Other solutions may include the adaption of the OctoPrint [controls](https://github.com/foosel/OctoPrint/wiki/Cookbook:-Custom-Controls) menu structure or use of the [REST API](http://docs.octoprint.org/en/master/api/job.html) of OctoPrint. These options are more difficult to implement.